# special characters strange behavior

Tags: mysql, utf-8

i have this string in my utf-8 mysql DB:
"Pruebá de eñes"

When i print it like plain text, everything works ok, but if i load that same field inside an input, textarea, etc, it becomes: "PruebÃ¡ de eÃ±es"

How can i solve this problem? =(

Comment: uhhh... nevermind. it seems all the input,textarea prints where passing through this: htmlentities($data,ENT_QUOTES) // previous programmer implemented that because it was a latin1_general_ci db.

Comment: Print to what? Console? Web page?

Comment: You should use `htmlspecialchars` and *not* `htmlentities` (unless you have a special reason to and know what you're doing). `htmlentities` will mess up non-ASCII characters unless you tell it the right `$charset` argument (the default is not sensible). **Don't** just remove `htmlentities` calls as you'll likely be introducing HTML-injection vulnerabilities (leading to XSS). Use `htmlspecialchars` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I recommend read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html (The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!) by Joel Spolsky) really useful.

Then if it's MySQL you can set the default character set in the connection by "SET NAMES 'utf8'". For example in Zend_Framework ($db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");)

Another option is add a filter to the data before print it in the screen. I made two handly functions ...

```
function utf8encode ($subject, $action = '//TRANSLIT')
{
   if ( @iconv( 'UTF-8', "UTF-8{$action}", $subject) == $subject ) {
                    #-- the value it's utf8
  } else {
                    $subject = utf8_encode ($subject);
  }

 return $subject;
```

}

```
function utf8decode ($subject, $action = '//TRANSLIT')
{
    if ( @iconv( 'UTF-8',  "UTF-8{$action}", $subject) == $subject ){
                      $subject = utf8_decode ($subject);
    } else {
                      #-- the value is probably ISO-8859-1
    }

 return $subject;
}
```